# How can I start a gStreamer pipeline at a specific position?

Tags: c#, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to start a non-live pipeline at a specific position.

I've tried doing a seek before setting the pipeline state to Playing, the seek returns 'true' but it does not take effect.

I'm able to perform a successful seek after playback has started, so I tried doing this immediately. It 'works' but I still get up to 2seconds of frames from the start before the seek takes effect.

Is there any way to ensure that no buffers are pushed before the seek? Or is any other better way of doing this entirely?

Here is my pipeline graph:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try setting pipeline state to PAUSED first, do the seek, then set state to change to PLAYING